# Monitor AMD/ATI GPU memory usage under linux

Tags: linux, memory, gpu, amd-graphics-card

Is there a way to monitor the GPU memory usage of ATI graphic cards under linux?
I found several solutions for nVidia graphic cards, but nothing for ATI graphic cards.

It might be possible with [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/), but i have not tried that yet.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Download and compile [radeontop](https://github.com/clbr/radeontop), if it's not part of your distro. 
Debian already contains it.

Usage: type `radeontop` in terminal then press <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Radeontop allows you to view your GPU utilization, both for the total activity percent and individual blocks.

Comment: Added instruction.

Comment: don't show memory usage, only GPU processing usage